# How to draw relationship-lines between columns?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Are there any options in MySQL Workbench to draw the relationship-line between the columns and not the tables? If i export my diagram as JPG i can't see, which columns are foreign keys and who they are related to.

On the screenshot, you can't see, that id and user_id are connected.

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the main menu bar go to: Model -> Relationship Notation -> Connect to columns.

Comment: Wooooooaahhr, how could I miss that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Hehe, I spent alot of time myself before i found that one, my pleasure Slevin.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure MySQL Workbench can draw relationship lines between columns but you can aware that **Primary Key** is shown as **Key Symbol** and **Foreign Key** is shown as **Red Diamond Symbol**.

Comment: As of Workbench 6, foreign primary keys are now shown as red key symbols too.